# Save as xlsx then close with out closing all workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I want to save the active workbook as xlsx and then close it without closing all the open excel workbooks. This code works but closes all the open excel files.

If I remove `Application.Quit` and leave `ThisWorkbook.Close` it will work only if I have more then one workbook open but if I only have the one workbook open it will close but leave a blank excel window open.

```
Sub SaveAsXlsx()

Dim varResponse As Variant
varResponse = MsgBox("Save As xlsx Removing Macros & Then Closes The Workbook", vbYesNo, "Save As xlsx")
If varResponse <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
FilePath = Left(FilePath, Len(FilePath) - 5) & " To Review" & ".xlsx"

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath, FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

'Enter Anything to Happen on xlsx Book Here
Range("A1").Select


ThisWorkbook.Save

FilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
MsgBox "Saved Review Copy As" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & FilePath, , "Saved!"

Application.Quit
ThisWorkbook.Close


End Sub
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. After closing `ThisWorkbook`, you want to leave Excel open if `Excel.Workbooks.Count > 0`, but you want to close the application if `Excel.Workbooks.Count = 0`?

Comment: @FreeMan I'm reading it that way as well. Seems like a `If Application.Workbooks.Count = 0 Then Application.Quit` might be the right way to go here?

Comment: That works but I had to change it to `If Application.Workbooks.Count = 1 Then Application.Quit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to *close* Excel if your code is closing the last open workbook, but leave it open if there are other workbooks open, you'll need to check the `Application.Workbook.Count` property, like this:

```
Sub SaveAsXlsx()

  Dim varResponse As Variant
  varResponse = MsgBox("Save As xlsx Removing Macros & Then Closes The Workbook", vbYesNo, "Save As xlsx")
  If varResponse <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Dim FilePath As String
  FilePath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
  FilePath = Left(FilePath, Len(FilePath) - 5) & " To Review" & ".xlsx"

  ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath, FileFormat:= _
                      xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

'Enter Anything to Happen on xlsx Book Here
  Range("A1").Select


  ThisWorkbook.Save

  FilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  MsgBox "Saved Review Copy As" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & FilePath, , "Saved!"

  ThisWorkbook.Close

  If Excel.Application.Workbooks.Count = 0 Then
    Application.Quit
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is what i wanted but i had to change it from `0` to `1` - `If Excel.Application.Workbooks.Count = 1 Then`